# Many to Many relationship in spring mvc

Tags: spring

Can anyone suggest me How to do many to many relationship in spring Mvc??
I am new to spring MVC. And I want to test a many to many relationship with a sample project. So in what kind of scenario I should use a many to many relationship??

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use hibernate as it is known as the best and dominated object/relational persistence (ORM) tool for Java developers. For Many to Many relationship please refer to this

http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in my project, i m using jdbc..is there any good tutorials for many to many relationship using jdbc??